# How to bind to an Android Spinner using a ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-spinner, android-viewmodel

I am trying to find out how to bind both the list items, and the selected value/index of an Android Spinner (I am pretty new to Android / Kotlin)

I have the following

```
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="com.example.app.Modes" />
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.app.MainActivityViewModel" />
    </data>

   ....

    <Spinner
        android:layout_row="17"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="1200px"
        android:entries="@{viewModel.devicesDescriptions}"
        app:selectedValue="@={viewModel.devicePosition}"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

and in the View Model

```
    val devicesDescriptions = ObservableArrayList<String>()
    var devices = listOf<MidiDeviceInfo>()
    fun setFoundDevices(d: MutableList<MidiDeviceInfo>) {
        devices = d
        for (dev in devices)
            devicesDescriptions.add(dev.toString())
    }
```

By trial and error I could set just strings to the Spinner items (the MidiDeviceInfo would have been better, but string will do)

However, I cannot get a binding to get the selectedItem to work.

I have tried many things, but with the above, I have the error

```
    Found data binding error(s):
    [databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a getter for \u003candroid.widget.Spinner app:selectedValue\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027java.lang.String\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml","pos":[{"line0":334,"col0":4,"line1":343,"col1":39}]}
```

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `android:selectedItemPosition="@={viewModel.devicePosition}"` instead of `app:selectedValue="@={viewModel.devicePosition}"`.

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou! As an aside, I wonder where you go to see all the possible properties? E.g. at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner it does not show much.

Comment: @peterc You can check out here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-attributes.

Comment: Thankyou, ok yes I see this one under the AdapterView. Great resource reference.